# Recording and playing audio in the background - iOS AVAudioSession Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm recording and playing audio using AVAudioSession. I set it up as follows:

```
AVAudioSession *sharedSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[sharedSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                              mode:AVAudioSessionModeHearingAccessibility
                           options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP
                             error:&localError];
```

All of this works fine within the app, but I'm having trouble keeping the record / playback going once the home button is pressed (when background is entered).

I added this to my plist based on looking at similar questions on SO:
[image]

This didn't have any effect. I think other options that are online such as "UIBackgroundModes" and putting "audio" as the value for the plist key are outdated since they don't seem to work with Xcode 9.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Did you activate the Audio Background Mode in the Xcode capabilities?

Comment: I don't see a way to set any capabilities if this is for a framework. Is there  away to activate it for a framework? (target is framework)